# Ubuntu 14.04 x64 HPmini 100-3100 getting stuck

Tags: 64-bit, shutdown, 32-bit

here is the thing:

I install last Ubuntu version in a **Hp mini 110-3100 with n455 1.66ghz 64bit I-Atom processor and 2gb RAM**, should i install Ubuntu 32bit? because, 64 bit is getting stuck for no reason and I have to do an **hard-shutdown** to my pc

**thanks!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To my knowledge, memory usage is higher on a 64bit operating system compared to a 32bit operating system, especially if you only have 2GB of RAM. So you could be handing out memory for nothing and ultimately.. causing your OS to get Frozen/Stuck.

**Conclusion:** Yes give a 32bit Operating System a go, but maybe just consider in upgrading from 2GB of Memory to 4GB of Memory, and make the most of 64bit processing.

**You're Welcome!**

Comment: Expensive in my contry to upgrade 2gb to 4gb.

Thanks for the quicky asnwer! i'll do that :D

Comment: Let us know how it goes!

Comment: Hello! Well, I have installed 32-bit version and the performance is not the same obviously, but well, till now,no frozen/stuck ocasions, if it happend, i'll instal 64-bit version again